# How to access the php.ini file

Tags: php, server, hosting, ini

I need to change some variables in the php.ini file to be able to upload files. I bought a domain & hosting, and i access it through FileZilla. Usisng phpinfo() I know

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path is /usr/local/php/p56
>
> Loaded Configuration File is /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/kristak/php/funwithhakase.pl/php56.ini

I don't know which of these files should I access and how to change the desired variables. I tried putting the adresses into FileZilla, but nothing appeared. Pls help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you should see your hosting documentation regarding specific access / permissions. 
You also did not mentioned what control panel you are using ( whm, cpanel, plesk , virtualmin, custom )

As for runtime :

You can use [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) in order to change some of the runtime variables.

It might not be available with your hosting, but you can always try ( most hosting that I have encountered allow it to some degree )

Likewise, you can use `ini_get` to see current values, for example to know what is the `upload_max_filesize` that is currently used :

```
echo 'upload_max_filesize = ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . "";
```

and to set it :

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','1024M');
```

or with error suppression :

```
@ini_set('upload_max_filesize',$my_Value);
```

Depending on your hosting, you could potentially do that with most variables of the `ini` file :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time','10');
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
ini_set('post_max_size','1024M');
```

Another way ( again - hosting permitting ) is to use `.htaccess`

Syntax is a bit different

```
php_value upload_max_filesize "80M"
php_value post_max_size "80M"
php_value max_execution_time "2000"
php_value memory_limit "150M"
```

Under some hosting that permit - you can actually put per-folder `user.ini` \ `.user.ini` or `php.ini` \ `.php.ini` with the values you want to override - but again, best is to consult hosting documentation.

If you want to make sure to know where is the used `ini` you can also try

```
<?php echo php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Properly you are not able to access the php.ini file. Maybe you can change some settings in your hosting backend. Otherwise contact the support of your hosting provider.